# Integrate Google classroom with site

Tags: google-classroom

I have some site and whant to integrate it with Google Classroom. Should users registred on my site have google account? The should be logged on my site via google?

Answer (score 0):

First, the only people that can use classroom are google apps for education accounts, not just any old google consumer account

If you are thinking that you will be creating and running the classroom classes where students would participate with their schools google account, that is not likely going to work unless you actually are a school/university(and even if it did there is a hard limit of 50 domains for classroom whitelisting)

It depends entirely on what you mean by "integrate". it you just want a user to be ablle to add a url from your site as a post or assignment then that is easy https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/sharebutton